# boxplot with mean points: getting the same order for categorical variable

Tags: r, mean, boxplot, categorical-data

I want to show boxplots with *mean* values in ***R***. My boxplots are representing catalase activity on 6 different sites, which I want to reorder from North to South with an Referent site at the end (N1,N2,M1,M2,S1,S2,R). I can easily reorder boxplots like this:

```
levels(data$site)
[1] "S2" "N1" "R" "N2" "S1" "M1" "M2"
x = factor(data$site,levels(data$site)[c(2,4,6,7,5,1,3)])
boxplot(catalase~x, data)
```

But *mean* values doesn't follow the new ordering.
I'm calling mean values like this:

```
means<-tapply(data$catalase, data$site, mean)
points(means, col="red", pch=19)
```

And tried reorder them like this:

```
reordered_means = factor(means,levels(means)[c(2,4,6,7,5,1,3)])
```

But obviously that doesn't make sence, since it's not working.
Suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is not

```
reordered_means = factor(means,levels(means)[c(2,4,6,7,5,1,3)])
```

but

```
reordered_means = means[c(2,4,6,7,5,1,3)]
```

---

**Example**

```
## toy data: z ~ site
site <- gl(7 , 5, labels = c("S2", "N1", "R", "N2", "S1", "M1", "M2"))
set.seed(0); z <- round(rnorm(35), 2)

## re-level
piv <- c(2,4,6,7,5,1,3)  ## pivoting index
x <- factor(site, levels(site)[piv])

## old mean before re-levelling
means <- tapply(z, site, mean)

## new mean after re-levelling
reordered_means <- means[piv]
#    N1     N2     M1     M2     S1     S2      R 
#-0.074 -0.370 -0.066 -0.226  0.206  0.788 -0.356 

## we can verify this by computing from scratch
reordered_means <- tapply(z, x, mean)
#    N1     N2     M1     M2     S1     S2      R 
#-0.074 -0.370 -0.066 -0.226  0.206  0.788 -0.356
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to recalculate the means after reordering in your dataset (and also maybe correct some little mistakes in the code)

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear)
boxplot(mpg~gear, mtcars)
means=tapply(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$gear, mean)
points(means, col="red", pch=19)

mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear, levels=levels(mtcars$gear)[c(2,3,1)])
means=tapply(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$gear, mean)
boxplot(mpg~gear, mtcars)
points(means, col="red", pch=19)
```

[image]